# How can I get the informations included in an UDP packet?

Tags: c#, stream, udp, packet

I stream a file with VLC (UDP) and i have to read the packets from my app. How can i get all the information from UDP (header and data)? i need them later..

Comment: Please identify exactly what header data you're after.  Most network stacks don't trivially expose "lower layer" protocol headers to the application layer.

Comment: i need all the data from header.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/dotnetwinpcap.aspx) is a nice tuttorial how to sniff data

For another way you can use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

Answer (score 0):

`WSARecvFrom` will get you the sender address from the header, along with the data (payload).  C# version is [`Socket.ReceiveFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivefrom.aspx).

If you need other header fields, there's `WSARecvMsg`, the C# version is [`Socket.ReceiveMessageFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivemessagefrom.aspx).

And, you should probably be using the async versions:  [`Socket.ReceiveFromAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivefromasync.aspx) and [`Socket.ReceiveMessageFromAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivemessagefromasync.aspx)

Comment: no.sorry i didn't explained very good. I receive the messages in a byte[] buffer and based on UDP packet structure i want to get the informations, i tryed this, but every packet has different numbers for source and destination port for example

Comment: i guess my mistake is because in that buffer i have only the payload of the UDP packet. If it is so, how can i get the header to?

Comment: @user1151849: Each of those functions fills in two buffers, one with the source information, one with the payload.  But in order to get the entire header, you'll need a raw socket.